# Cannot Deploy Application on Eclipse (Bluemix)

Tags: eclipse, deployment, ibm-cloud, devops, ibm-cloud-tools

I am trying to create my first web app on Bluemix.

1. I created a Java Liberty Runtime and downloaded the Starter Code to
   work on Eclipse.
2. I installed IBM Bluemix tools to Eclipse and
   imported the starter code as an archive file.

When I try to run application on IBM Bluemix Server, it is recognizing the starter code as another new application and saying `"There is a deployed application with the same name."` So, I cannot update the application on eclipse and also there is two different applications are being seen on server view:

[image]

When I try to go application homepage it is giving:

```
Not Found
The application or context root for this request has not been found: /
```

Thanks for any comments.

Comment: Can you share your `manifest.yml` file?

Comment: Can you clarify whether you originally deployed your code to Bluemix before importing your project into Eclipse? Based on your server view, it looks like you already have an instance running in Bluemix.  When you are publishing your app, it is not recognizing the app in your workspace as that same app in Bluemix.

Comment: Manifest.yml: `applications:
- disk_quota: 1024M
  host: e-urlabel
  name: e-urlabel
  path: webStarterApp.war
  domain: eu-gb.mybluemix.net
  instances: 1
  memory: 512M`

Comment: @samet your manifest file looks fine, what is the directory structure of your application?  It sounds like your WEB-INF.xml doesn't know where the root  of your app is?

Comment: @JeffSloyer do you mean ibm-web-ext.xml ?

Comment: Im sorry I meant web.xml, check out this project for an example of a properly built WAR file and app. https://hub.jazz.net/project/jsloyer/talent-manager/overview#https://hub.jazz.net/git/jsloyer%252Ftalent-manager/list/master/personafusion/WebContent

Comment: @JeffSloyer can you please take a look at https://hub.jazz.net/project/cen506/e-urlabel

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The IBM Eclipse Tools for Bluemix recently added the ability to map and unmap a Bluemix app with a project in your workspace: https://developer.ibm.com/bluemix/2015/04/02/updates-ibm-eclipse-tools-bluemix/

> To map a project, right click on an existing application in the Servers view and select Map to Project.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I just realized and solved issue with the same method that you specified :)

Answer (score 3):

I was able to get this to work.  I modified the `manifest.yml` file a bit to have a unique name and hostname.  When you deploy this change the hostname and name to something unique.

```
applications:
- disk_quota: 1024M
  host: e-urlabel-jbs
  name: e-urlabel-jbs
  path: webStarterApp.war
  domain: mybluemix.net
  instances: 1
  memory: 512M
```

Note. I changed the domain as my account is in the US instance, but for yours to work change it to `eu-gb.mybluemix.net`.

Comment: Jeff, thanks for the help. It seems like there was two problem. By mapping two projects (local and remote one) i solved the issue :)

Answer (score 1):

I just realized that there is a recent update which provides ability to map and unmap Bluemix apps with projects in the workspace. It has come with the fresh version of the Eclipse Bluemix Tools. I solved the issue by mapping my Starter Code and Bluemix Project:

1. right click on an existing application in the Servers view
2. select Map to Project

Source: https://developer.ibm.com/bluemix/2015/04/02/updates-ibm-eclipse-tools-bluemix/